# using dcount with datepart function in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use the dcount function to check if the "fakturen" are already made for this year. It doesnt seem to work properly.
This is my code:

```
If DCount("*", "fakturen", "[DatePart('yyyy', [fakturen].[faktuurDatum])] = #" & [DatePart('yyyy', Forms![f_fakturen]![faktuurDatum])] & "#") > 0 Then
  strFoutmelding = "Facturen al aanwezig"
  GoTo Jaar_fakturen_Click_Error
End If
```

I used the following code as an example:

```
' Dates
variable = DCount("[FieldName]", "TableName", "[Criteria] = #" & Forms!FormName!ControlName & "#")
' ***************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not year?

```
Year(faktuurDatum)

"Year(faktuurDatum)=" & Year(Forms![f_fakturen]![faktuurDatum])
```

If you really want DatePart:

```
If DCount("*", "fakturen", "DatePart('yyyy',[faktuurDatum]) = " _
    & DatePart("yyyy", Forms![f_fakturen]![faktuurDatum])) > 0 Then
```

`Datepart('yyy' ...` will return a number, not a date, so you do not need delimiters.